# Find the position of distinct area, between two images by using HOG Features

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, visualization, detection

Suppose we have two images. Both images are the same. The only different between them is that one of the images has a small filled circle on center. I can extract and visualize HOG features like this example:

http://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html

And then calculate the Euclidean distance between two images by using hog features. In this case all hog features will be zero except the parts which related to filled circle area.
BUT I don’t know how can I find the position of filled circle (the distinct area) and highlight it.

Hint: for example, for detecting people we can use this method:

I = insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',bboxes,scores);

http://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.peopledetector-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substract two matrices, then find the bounding box on the result.

Comment: I calculate the Euclidean_distance like this:
Euclidean_distance = sqrt(sum((hog_img2 – hog_img1).^2))
Now I have one matrix (e.g, Euclidean_distance = 1*256) of hog feature. But I don’t know how to fine the position of circle by using these hog feature.

Comment: You are complicating the easy task. After substraction, everything will be 0 or near to 0, if two images aren't 100% the same except the circle. The circle will somewhat change in the result but only it will be present, on a black or near black background.

Comment: If you don't have a function to find the bounding box in ML or some toolbox, then you have to find the square encapsulating your cyrcle. You just iterate and find the first occurence of non zero minimally distanced from the left border, then the last non zero toward the right (even can look at the same row), and you already have the 2*R of your circle. If you want the centre, it's enough to get it. If you want the BBox, you do the same for bottom and top occurences and combine their X's and Y's into the rectangle surrounding the circle.

Comment: OK, I simplify the problem. I just subtract the hog features instead of using Euclidean distance.
I need to highlight and show any non-zero 'hog3' on image **by using hog, not pixel**.
Note: (hog3=hog2Img2 - hog1Img1= all vectors are zero except the vectors which related to circle. It is matrix of 1*256)

Comment: I told you how to do it. after changing your pictures to black and white (only one value per pixel) matrices, do abs(img1-img2), then find the area fitting non zero values. Problem with HOG is that it gives you just descriptors. That's not enough to do anything meaningful without other techniques. Anyway, calculate the HOG over the abs(img1-img2), it will be clearer, and then you will have to know the general HOG for a circle. Then you will have to use some machine learning algo to find the circle. SVM or ANN or some basic classification algo. And even this won't work if you have 1D matrix.

Comment: I.e. a vector as HOG result. You won't be able to pin point the location. So it's better, in my opinion, to search for centroides, then see what is in them using HOG. I'e' use my simplified algo to bring centroides to front, isolate them, then check their HOG features to see whether they are circle or not.

Comment: Here, read this article, it describes some HOG usages in pattern recognition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients

Comment: Woops, now I see that I expressed myself a bit poorly in a comment above. By centroides I really meant blobs in a pict, their centroides are their points of mass. A position of a pixel(s) to which all points of a blob gravitate. For your circle, its centroid is its centre. I hope i helped you somewhat. No thanks needed.